# Symfony : PHP Session variable lost

Tags: php, symfony, session

My Web application is meant to be used using a touch device and uses Symfony PHP framework server-side.

As the application is hit in *kiosk* mode (aka. fullscreen) with Google Chrome, I redirect the user on a special URL where a session variable is set. All works fine.

The issue is, I never act on this variable elsewhere while the user interact with the application however sometimes the session variable vanishes from session storage.

I set my variable like this :

```
<?php 
     $this->session->set('XXX', $request->get('XXX'));
?>
```

There is no problem with settig the session variable but sometimes the session variable is lost and I have to restart Google Chrome for the session variable to be set again.  :\

Comment: And I access to the session variable with : app.session.get('fridge_id')

Comment: Did you check your `session.gc_maxlifetime` php.ini configuration value?

Comment: This is a very good answer. The default value was set, I set it to 1 year now. I'll test it tomorrow. Thanks !